# sum of continuous values in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, max, continuations

I need to calculate the following in matlab.

EDIT EDIT: I alway have a 16 x 3 matrix. 16 rows and 3 columns.
The 3 columns represent R,G,B and the 16 rows represent points. From 1-16.
An example matrix looks like this:

**1 1 1** 
**-1** 0 0 
0 0 **1** 
**1** 0 0 
**-1** 0 0 
**1** 0 **-1** 
**1 1 1** 
 
**1 1 1** 
0 0 0 
-1 0 1 
1 0 0 
0 0 1 
1 0 1 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
**1** 0 **1**

Now I need to know are there 11 coherently rows which have min. 1 value ~= 0 in each column?
In the above example the first 8 rows and the last row have in each column min 1 value and are coherently. So this 9 rows are the max coherently rows without a complete zero row between.

Sry that my first post wasn't correct.

I've do that with a really poor for-solution. Is there a faster way (vectorized) to do that?

```
for i=1:16
   for j=0:16
      if i+j > 16
         value = (i+j)-16;
      else
         value = i+j;
      end
      if table(value,1) ~= 0 || table(value,2) ~= 0 || table(value,3) ~= 0
         equal = equal + 1;
         if equal >= 11
            copy(y,x) = 1;
            equal = 0;
            break;
         end
         else
            equal = 0;
         end
      end
   end
end
```

And the 16 points are circular. This min the first point and the last point connect.

Thanks for help and sry for the confusing.

Comment: your edit just confused the question. write a sample matrix, show your solution etc...

Comment: Why not use a complete minimal sample data. You have used `1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 ` which is just a row vector and is enough to confuse others. Use a better sample data and post your loop solution! Thanks for helping us help you.

Comment: yes you're right. Sorry for this. I EDIT my post again and hope my question is a bit more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This counts the number of coherent rows with at least one none-zero entry *without circularity*:

```
B = ~(A==0);
idx = find(sum(B,2) == 0);
result = max([idx;size(A,1)+1] - [0;idx]) - 1;
```

Now you can check whether `result` is bigger than 11.

Another way would be:

```
B = ~(A==0);
C = bwconncomp(sum(B,2)>0);
num = cellfun(@numel,C.PixelIdxList);
result = max(num);
```

EDIT 2: To account for circularity, i.e. rows at the beginning and the end should be counted as coherent, you could do

```
B = ~(A==0);
idx = find(sum(B,2) == 0);
result = max([idx;size(A,1)+idx;size(A,1)+1] - [0;idx;size(A,1)+idx]) - 1;
```

EDIT: I edited the `result`-line in the first solution according to Knedlsepp's comments.

Comment: If there are all ones, the first one won't work. But it could be fixed with someting like `result = max([idx(1:end);size(A,1)+1] - [0;idx(1:end)]) - 1;`

Comment: Just realized that the `(1:end)` is superfluous now. :-)

Comment: :-D I'm sorry for constantly commenting here, but the `+1` is still missing ;-)

Comment: It's not yours to apologize! Sorry for being so sloppy

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat clunky solution, but it should give a solution at least if the matrix isn't too big. If you call your matrix `m` try the following line of code:

```
log2(max([cumprod(2*logical(m),2),ones(size(m,1),1)],[],2))
```

I hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Now that it is clear what is ment by the question, here's an answer that should work:

```
find(~[m(:,1)|m(:,2)|m(:,3);0],1)-1 >= 11
```

Comment: I think this fails on vectors like  `[0     1     1     0     1]` but you're at the right direction....

Comment: yes. Thanks @ Jens but fails on vectors which not beginn with 1

Comment: I've edited my answer so it works in the case where the first entry is zero too. You should notice however that my solution is not always faster than a simple `for` loop using something like `find([m(i,:),0]==0,1)-1`. If there are many rows my solution is best, if there are many columns the `for` solution is better.

Comment: Sry for that mistake but I edit my main-post because my question wasn't correct.